# Ionic 3 date time picker not showing days

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, datetimepicker

I am using the following code to show a date time picker with the weekly days only. But the picker is only showing numbers from 1 to 31.

```
     <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
          <ion-datetime displayFormat="DDDD" pickerFormat="DDDD">
          </ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

The documentation of ionic date picker says "DDDD" will show the full name of days. But it's not working. Can somebody explain where I am wrong?[image: This is my code]

I want to have the name of days, like- sunday, monday, tuesday in the list of date time picker.

Comment: Same problem for me, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide your code using https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

The name of days are displayed only when the date is selected and the date picker is closed, not in the date picker interface that is open and shown in the bottom of the screen, as you show in your picture.

You may want to try this plugin as an alternative to `ion-datetime`:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/date-picker/

or

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-datetimepicker

Comment: Ionic date time picker has two different format type settings. "Picker format" and "display format". If the value of picker format sat to "DDDD" then picker interface should display the full name of the weekly days, and the display format of "DDDD" is for the result of selected date, which will display full name of selected weekly day after the picker closed. So they have made the format setting for two different places- picker interface and input value.
And the native date picker plugin that you have suggested me doesn't have any option for displaying only weekly days.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and honestly because this is not available inside the ion-datetime picker I just decided to use my own `select` just for the days then user the picker for the time.

```
     <ion-item>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedDay">
            <ion-option [value]="day" *ngFor="let day of daysOfWeek">{{ day }}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="h:00 a" pickerFormat="h a" [(ngModel)]="selectedHour"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
```

And daysOfWeek is just an array:

```
 daysOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednsday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
```

Then with the `selectedDay` and the `selectedHour` I can create my timestamp however.

Answer (score 0):

So Ionic replaces the `DDD` and `DDDD` in the `pickerFormat`. I have no idea why.
This code is in the `ion-datetime` template:

`template.replace('DDDD', '{~}').replace('DDD', '{~}');`

If you must display the day in the picker, best will be to use an external module, like [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) or make your own `select` with array of the days.

Answer (score 0):

Hey here you can get DAY MONTH YEAR and HOUR MINUTE, if you want , you can remove HOUR and MINUTE

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMM, YYYY  HH:mm" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" cancelText="Annuler" doneText="Valider" #datePicker"></iondatetime>
```